# FOP - prevent block collapsing

Tags: apache-fop

I would like to show a tickbox on the pdf and tried to do it as:

```
  <fo:table-row height="10pt">
      <fo:table-cell>
       <fo:block line-height="10pt" text-align="center" border-style="solid" border="1pt" white-space-collapse="false">
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block/>
   </fo:table-cell>  
</fo:table-row>
```

but instead of getting a box, I get a line ie a box width 1pt height.
How can I force FOP, not to collapse the block? I'm using Apache-Fop 1.0

Update1:

This works:

```
 <fo:block text-align="left">
     <fo:table text-align="left" table-layout="fixed">                                            
         <fo:table-column column-width="10pt"/>
         <fo:table-column column-width="10pt"/>                                            
         <fo:table-body>
             <fo:table-row height="10pt">
                 <fo:table-cell height="10pt">
                     <fo:block line-height="10pt" font-family="$_Fontfamily"
                               font-size="8pt">$row.getValue().get(0)
                     </fo:block>
                 </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell height="10pt" width="10pt">
            <fo:block text-align="center" border-style="solid" border="1pt"/>
          </fo:table-cell>                                             
             </fo:table-row>
         </fo:table-body>
     </fo:table>
 </fo:block>
```

I want border on the second cell.
If I put a table into the second block, then it works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell height="10pt" width="10pt">
    <fo:block text-align="center" border-style="solid" border="1pt"/>
  </fo:table-cell>
  <fo:table-cell height="10pt">
    <fo:block/>
  </fo:table-cell>  
</fo:table-row>
```

This is a real world example it produces two cells with the given measurements

```
<fo:table border="1pt solid black" width="18.5cm" table-layout="fixed">
  <fo:table-body>
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell height="20.0cm" width="16.3cm" border-right="1pt solid black">
        <fo:block/>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell height="20.0cm">
        <fo:block/>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help :-(

Comment: As I don't know your table spec, it's hard to tell, i've given a real world example that is working. Although we use 0.95.

Comment: Thanks. It works if I put a table into the block, but I wanted to solve it with a simplier structure

Comment: I think you should put width on the second table-cell, and make sure the surrounding table has sufficient space to accomodate the cells, table-columns are not necessary

Comment: Or, you could go with a block-container as well.